# Métodos de Publicação Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deploy, build

Existe alguma forma de publicar arquivos específicos através do Visual Studio 2013?

Nas publicações que realizei, o Visual Studio deletou todos os arquivos no destino e importou os novos.

Obs.: Utilizo o método de publicação "File System".

Comment: Caso queira publicar um arquivo específico você pode utilizar o atalho Alt +ç , Alt+P.

Você também pode no perfil de publicação desmarcar a opção de deletar todos os arquivos.

Comment: @Jhonathan. 

1. Não marquei a opção "delete all existing files prior to publish" e mesmo assim o visual studio excluiu todos os arquivos.

2. Não consegui utilizar as teclas de atalho para realizar a publicação.

Comment: @Jhonathan, consegui realizar com os atalhos.

Answer (score 1):

Vai na propriedades de seu projeto (botão direito do mouse > propriedades || <kbd>ALT + Enter</kbd> em cima do projeto), na aba **Publish**. Lá você encontra o botão <kbd>Application Files</kbd> e selecione os que quer publicar.

[Esta página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) da Microsoft explica melhor os usos e como suas definições.

Comment: Estranho, neste caminho que você me passou conforme descrito no site da Microsoft, não existe o botão "Application Files", e aba "Publish", na versão do meu Visual Studio, está com o nome "Package/Publish Web".

Comment: @PedroFilipe Você está desenvolvendo em que? ASp.NET MVC, WinForms, etc?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms