# Publicar arquivos específicos pelo visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Através desta pergunta [Métodos de Publicação Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113315/m%C3%A9todos-de-publica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-visual-studio) descobri como publicar arquivos específicos através do Visual Studio. Posso selecionar os arquivos que quero publicar, clicar com o botão direito e selecionar a opção "Publish selected files" ou utilizar as teclas de atalho.

Quando faço isso, os arquivos .cs são postados no servidor, porém é necessário que eles sejam convertidos em DLL, correto? Como faço isso? Estou publicando da maneira correta?

Outra coisa que reparei foi que, no meu projeto, eu não tenho uma DLL para cada code-behind.

Obs.: Utilizo o Visual Studio 2013.